# Rxjava2 "blockingGet" causes Unable to resolve host: No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, rx-java2

I've `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in my manifest file.

The error I get is:

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xxx": No address associated with hostname
       at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow(ExceptionHelper.java:45)
       at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet(BlockingMultiObserver.java:91)
       at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2492)
```

This bug appeared when I started using `blockingGet` for first time.

```
        List<Data> dataList = dataRepository.getDataFromApi().blockingGet();
```

DataRepository:

```
fun getDataFromApi(): Single<List<Data>> {
    return dataService.getData()
            .map { jsonApiObject ->
                ...
                return@map data
            }
}
```

If I understand correctly, it happens when internet is lost. How to fix this and whats wrong with my approach?

**UPDATE**:

Trying to catch this exception like this:

```
try {
    val data = repository!!.getData().blockingGet()
    ...
} catch (e: SocketException) {
    showNetworkErrorDialog()
}
```

Error still appears.

Comment: Just for clarity `blockingGet` is not responsible, it merely reports an issue originating from elsewhere.

Comment: I run it with debugger. It works okay if I have internet. If I turn off internet before, it crashes. How should I implement onError exceptions for blockingGet?

Comment: It is a blocking terminal operation so you have to try-catch it yourself. Have you considered not using it and go with `subscribe`?

Comment: @akarnokd Can you give me an example of try-catch that catches not specific error but all possible errors just like onError()?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Java language and how catching exceptions work in Java?

Comment: @akarnokd I updated my approach

Comment: "Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException" and you are catching?

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#blockingGet--

Answer (score 0):

Check the internet connection for this URL. It looks like your application just can't reach the host